# How to use Angular Scenario Runner to run a subset of the test suite?

Tags: angularjs, tdd, angular-scenario

I am developing an application based on TDD.

For the server-side everything is fine as Python test runner are great.

For JS, I start using mocha which is also great.

I have wrote my first tests with Karma and Angular Scenario Runner and it also great.

The problem is that soon after starting to use Angular Scenario Runner in real life I ended up with 60 e2s tests. Running all tests takes 1 minute.

Now, when I write a new test, each time I want to check the test, I will have to wait up to 60 seconds.

In Mocka there is this option to running only a specific test with .only http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#exclusive-tests

---

It looks like Angular Scenario Runner is briefly documented, but somehow mimics Jasmine.

---

Looking at Angular Scenario Runner code I could only find the xit definition, for skipping a test.

Is there a trick to ask Angular Scenario Runner to only run a subset of the test?

I have implemented an xdescribe blank method to skip a whole suite... but this is feasible for the long term.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can run a subset of tests.

Use `iit` instead of `it` on the tests you would like to run and the others will be skipped.

Example:

```
describe('TestCtrl', function() {

    var $scope;

    iit('should have scope', function() {
        expect($scope).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have scope', function() {
        expect($scope).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have scope', function() {
        expect($scope).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

This will cause only the first test to be run and the others to be skipped.

As soon as Jasmine detects a test with `iit`, it will skip the all tests with `it`.

This is very handy if you need to test only one or two tests you are working on when you have defined a whole suite of tests.

This also works when you replace `describe` with `ddescribe` to run only blocks with `ddescribe`.

As soon as you remove all `iit` and `ddescribe` calls, all tests will be run again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This helps a lot! Many thanks. I saw the iit in the source code, but i did not take a closer look, thinking is just an alias for xit... and Jasmine documentation does not mention anything about 'iit'.